# find the count of rows between the specified range of rows in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I have an excel with three columns contains different values as below,

```
main_df =
    | a  |  b  |  c  |
    | -- | ----|---  |
    | 10 | 0.5 |  53 |
    | 12 | 0.9 |  78 |
    |18  | 1.7 |  81 |
    |23  |2.8  |  93 |
    |46  | 3.5 |  99 |
    |49  | 3.7 |  100 |
    |51  | 3.8 |  107 |
```

and I have another rangr_df contains, the quantiles(continuous intervals with equal probabilities) to be counted in between the rows as,

```
    |label| Q1 |  Q2 | Q3 |
    | -- | ----|---  |--- |
    | a  |  12 |  23 | 51 |
    | -- | ----|---  |----|
    | b  | 0.5 | 1.7 | 3.8|
    | -- | ----|---  |----|
    | c  | 78  |  93 | 107|
```

I need to separate the values and print the count  which lies between 12-23-51 in  a, 0.5-1.7-3.8 in b and 78-93-107 in c in main_df.

Can any one suggest the syntax to find the count of rows between two ranges?

Answer (score 1):

If those are quantiles, you probably want to include the smaller numbers as well. So for 'a': (0-12], (12-23], (23-51]. And so on.

It's only a few steps but I'll explain each:

First, if `labels` is not an index, make it the index of `rangr_df` so it becomes:

```
         Q1    Q2     Q3
label                   
a      12.0  23.0   51.0
b       0.5   1.7    3.8
c      78.0  93.0  107.0
```

Create a 'Q0' column filled with 0's as the left-most column:

```
rangr_df.insert(0, 'Q0', 0)
```

Loop over each of the Q- columns and labels to get the number of items falling in between the ranges, which doesn't include the minimum but includes the maximum:

```py
res = pd.DataFrame()  # empty DF to store the results
for label in rangr_df.index:
    for Qx, Qy in zip(rangr_df.columns, rangr_df.columns[1:]):
        res.loc[label, Qy] = sum(
            (rangr_df.loc[label, Qx] < main_df[label]) &
            (main_df[label] <= rangr_df.loc[label, Qy])
        )

res = res.astype(int)  # if you want the counts as integers
```

- `sum` is used because `True` evaluates to 1 and `False` evaluates to 0:
- `zip(rangr_df.columns, rangr_df.columns[1:])` provides each of the columns in pairs - `(Q0, Q1), (Q2, Q3), ...`. The Q0 column is required for the lower limit comparison of Q1.

  - If you prefer, that can be removed and add an extra `if` clause to check Q1 differently from the others.

Result:

```
   Q1  Q2  Q3
a   2   2   3
b   1   2   4
c   2   2   3
```

---

Edit: An option with [`DF.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

Setup `rangr_df` as before (with the 'Q0' column). Then create `range_counts()` which will accept each row as a series of Q's and compare them with `main_df`:

```py
def range_count(s, main_df):
    res = pd.Series(dtype='int')
    res['Q0'] = 0  # for 'broadcast' to work
    for Qx, Qy in zip(s.index, s.index[1:]):
        res[Qy] = sum(
            (s[Qx] < main_df[s.name]) & (main_df[s.name] <= s[Qy])
        )
    return res
```

Use it as:

```
rangr_df.apply(range_count, axis=1, result_type='broadcast', main_df=main_df).loc[:, 'Q1':].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
larger_than_Q1 = quantile_df["Q1"]['a'] < main_df['a']
smaller_than_Q2 = main_df['a'] < quantile_df["Q2"]['a']

print(len(main_df['a'][larger_than_Q1 & smaller_than_Q2]))
```

Taking the values from the quantiles frame, we can filter the original by values between them and take the length of the resulting series.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood well the question but this should work in your case :
For exemple if you wish to have the number of rows in **a** between Q1 and Q2

```
idx = (quantile_df.Q2['a'] < 23) & (main_df.a > quantile_df.Q1['a'])
main_df.a[idx].count()
```